# How can I test my chassis speaker on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, speakers

I have an Asrock AD525PV3 with a chassis speaker connected. I want to test it, but have no idea how.

I have Ubuntu Server installed and tried to use `espeak`, but it failed with an error:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2212:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2212:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2212:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

At this point, I don't know if it's `espeak` that fails, or if the chassis speaker simply isn't connected in a right way. Or does Ubuntu have to be configured?

Comment: I *think* the beep command should activate the chassis speaker.

Comment: yes. I think so too, I cannot be 100% sure, but I think with speaker connected beep is louder.